# Is there an easy way to zero time with each new condition in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, loops

I have a big-ass time series data frame where one condition changes at variable intervals. I would like to zero the time with each new condition, so I converted the categories into integers and created a new column using the .diff() to indicate the rows where the switch occurs with non-zero values. Then I made a new column, "Mod_time" as a container for the new time values that zero at each new condition. This is what I want the table to look like:

| Time | Condition | Numerical Condition | Fruit_switch | Mod_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Apples | 6 | nan | 0 |
| 1 | Apples | 6 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | Apples | 6 | 0 | 2 |
| 3 | Apples | 6 | 0 | 3 |
| 4 | Oranges | 2 | -4 | 0 |
| 5 | Oranges | 2 | 0 | 1 |

I tried iterrows:

```
for index, row in gas_df.iterrows(): 

   if row['gas_switch'] != 0:
       gas_df.loc[[index], ["Mod_time"]] = 0
   
   else:
       gas_df.loc[[index], ["Mod_time"]] = gas_df.loc[[str(int(index)-1)], ["Mod_time"]] + 1
```

But got the error "None of [Index(['0'], dtype='object')] are in the [index]" It seems that iterrows is blind to everything but the one row it's looking at.

I also tried using enumerate instead of iterrows and got the same error.

Any suggestions or search terms would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a whole garden variety of problems that involve cumulative sum with reset.  This one can be seen as such: you'd like to do the cumulative sum of time differences, with reset when the "numerical condition" changes.

```py
import numpy as np

def cumsum_reset(v, reset):
    v = v.copy()
    c = np.cumsum(~reset)
    v[reset] = -np.diff(np.r_[0, c[reset]])
    return np.cumsum(v)


# application
cond = df['Numerical Condition']
df['Mod_time'] = cumsum_reset(np.diff(np.r_[0, df['Time']]),cond != cond.shift())
```

On your data:

```py
   Time Condition  Numerical Condition  Fruit_switch  Mod_time
0     0    Apples                    6           NaN         0
1     1    Apples                    6           0.0         1
2     2    Apples                    6           0.0         2
3     3    Apples                    6           0.0         3
4     4   Oranges                    2          -4.0         0
5     5   Oranges                    2           0.0         1
```

**Edit**

From the comments, it sounds like the reset should really come from when `df['Condition']` (the fruit name) changes. Also, the time difference between the rows is always one. Therefore, the following should work as well:

```py
c = df['Condition']
df['Mod_time'] = cumsum_reset(np.ones_like(c), c.shift() != c)
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It almost works, but the mod_time starts at increasingly negative values with each subsequent condition. And occasionally repeats itself (-5, -5, -4, ...)

Comment: I should add that it works a lot better with the when the index column is used to calculate the Mod_index, so there's probably something funny with my data, but the two first values still repeat (0, 0, 1, 2, ...)

Comment: Is the answer working on the example data with your version of pandas & Python? If so, then what is different in your "actual" problem? If not, why not? Also, do you have cycles where `condition` goes back to a value previously seen? If so, what behavior do you expect (my answer just looks for transitions, not groupings by `condition`).

Comment: The conditions cycle between 6 categories, but I do want them to reset to zero in each cycle. It looks like the negative values accumulate when there are missing time values in the previous category, so that if there is one missing value in apples, the Mod_time of oranges will start from -1. If there is then also a missing value in oranges, the next category will start from -2.  The double values were happening because I was using Fruit_switch as the 'condition', oops.

Comment: The solution provided does not accommodate missing data points (rows), yielding negative Mod_time values at the reset. I would expect each new category to instead reset to zero even when missing time values are present.

Comment: can you provide a better example that shows what's happening in that case and what the desired output should be instead?